# How to access a member of an object in a stack? C++

Tags: c++

How to assign/read a member of an object in a stack?

```
struct item{
    char opra; 
    int count;
    double operand;
};
stack<item> S;
double test = S.top.operand;
```

it not works, thanks.

Comment: The error :" 'operand' must have class/struct/union" is shown

Comment: If you want to add additional information, please [edit] your question.

Comment: Typo: `S.top.operand` --> `S.top().operand`?

Answer (score 1):

Top is a method, so you should call `S.top().operand`. I got it to compile like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

struct item{
    char opra;
    int count;
    double operand;
};


int main(){
        std::stack<item> S;
        double test = S.top().operand;
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just making a typo.
top in stack is a function, I let you here a working example:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stack> 
using namespace std; 

struct item{
    char opra; 
    int count;
    double operand;
};


int main() 
{ 
    item a;
    a.opra = 'a';
    a.count = 3;
    a.operand = 5.0;
    stack<item> S;
    S.push(a);

    // Stack top 
    cout << S.top().operand; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```sh
5
```